# How to Modify your image or command line so that the program looks for files in that directory

Tags: configmap

how to Modify our image or command line so that the program looks for files in that directory. Each key in the ConfigMap data map becomes the filename under mountPath.
Is below code doing the same thing ?

volumeMounts:
- name: Test-ip-volume
mountPath: /etc/conf

```
  volumes:
   - name: Test-ip-volume
     projected:
      sources:
      - configMap:
          name: app-config
```

Do I need to add more code in it or it is fine for above requirement